# Python (lists): how to group duplicate labels, summing up their respective values

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I have 2 lists in Python 3.7: one for labels and other for values.
Each of the labels contains one respective value and there are duplicated labels.

How can I remove these duplicates in the list of labels, summing up all their respective values?

## Example of what I have:

```
labels = ['05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019']
values = ['2', '5', '7', '4']
```

## What I need is:

```
labels = ['05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019']
values = ['14', '4']
```

Comment: can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

labels = ['05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019']
values = ['2', '5', '7', '4']

c = Counter(l for l, v in zip(labels, values)
              for _ in range(int(v)))
# Counter({'05/Feb/2019': 14, '01/Feb/2019': 4})

labels = list(c)
# ['05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019']

values = list(c.values())
# [14, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way would be to create a default dict and then unwrap it

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(float)

for label, value in zip(labels, values):
    result[label] += float(value)

labels, values = zip(*result.items())
```

Comment: is there any special way for installing it? Could not import it.

Comment: @JulioSouto: it's built-in. Added the `import` to the answer

Comment: I changed it for float, since I have decimals and this is what the server returned: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'float' and 'str'

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group both lists zipped together, and add the elements in `values` with common `labels`:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

z = zip(labels,values)
r = [(k, sum(int(i[1]) for i in v)) for k,v in groupby(z, key=itemgetter(0))]
labels, values = map(list, zip(*r))

print(labels)
# ['05/Feb/2019', '01/Feb/2019']

print(values)
# [14, 4]
```

Comment: @yatu I need 2 separate lists. One for labels and one for values.

Comment: I keep having duplicated labels. The actual output is: ['(air)', 'MONTE ROSA', '(air)', 'NORTHERN GUARD', '(air)']. See here that I have '(air)' being repeated.

Comment: @JulioSouto , for the input data you've provided, this solution works fine. If it doesn't is for some peculiarity on the data not present in the input you've shared. Try sharing a larger sample